# Calling Google sheets Cells into Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets

I have the following script that worked great until recently. I used it to get google sheets cell data to a widget on my phone. I believe google did an update that is not allowing it to call the data because when I run the url it now  shows up as page not available. Is their a way to get this working again? I use the app Scriptable to create the widget on my phone.

```
const endpoint =
"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1QKFmpeu_-YIoYG3sDiCBflyaGTE7WT-mk00zwL6Q0_o/1/public/full?alt=json"
// Function that performs the request to the JSON endpoint
async function loadItems() {
        let at = endpoint
        let req = new Request(at)
        let corpo = await req.loadJSON()
        // We return just the cells
        return corpo.feed.entry
}
// Request the spreadsheet data
let json = await loadItems()

// Obtaining the content of the exact cell we are looking for
first= json[10].gs$cell["$t"]

// Create the widget
let w = new ListWidget()
w.backgroundColor= Color.black()

// Add the value of the stock to the widget
t = w.addText(first)
t.textColor = Color.blue()
t.font = new Font("ALGERIAN", 11)
t.shadowOffset= new Point(50,50)
t.shadowColor= Color.white()



Script.setWidget(w)
Script.complete()
```

Comment: Hi there! I see that you want to get some cell data, have you considered the [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api)? In particular the [`Range.getValue`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) method. Is this a valid approach in your situation?